# Force DIV to wrap text, regardless of parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

So I have a `div` buried in a fixed table. I have some `word-wrap` and other msic CSS on `td` and `div` elements. However, when I get to my child `div`, I want to ignore all inheritance and wrap my text without breaking the word.

```
#row4 td > div, textarea{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;  
    white-space: pre; /* needed for Chrome to maintain tabs, spaces, etc */
}
#div_contents{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

.

```
<tr id="row4">
    <td>
        <div id="div_search_results" class="results" ></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="div_contents"></div>
        <textarea id="ta_contents"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This causes overflow bars and doesn't wrap my content. However, if I use `word-wrap: break-word;`, I get wrapped content, but it breaks within the word.

Regardless of parent blocks, breaks, wraps, and whatever, can't I override my child `div` for normal wrapped text?

Here is a CSS screenshot from Chrome:
[image]

Comment: have you tried targeting #div_contents using child selectors ie. #row4 > td > #div_contents

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. This ended up being `<pre>` tags added from the `highlight.js` addon.